# JavaScript callback function

Tags: javascript

please help 
I have a simple example here

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function test(callback1) {
        callback1();
    }
    var f1 = function () {
        alert(1);
    }
</script>
```

Currently, parameter of the test function is a function, when abc button is clicked, test function will be called and then test will call f1. Everything okie with me.

However, I'd like a small change like this: parameter of the test function will be a string, I mean it should be a function name, test('f1') instead of test(f1).
Is it possible?How can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function name as a string...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/javascript-function-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window[callback1]();`

Depending on use I would prefer prepare separate functions map.

```
var funcMap = {
   f1: function() {...},
   ...
};
funcMap['f4'] = function() {...};
function test(callback1) {
    funcMap[callback1]();
}
```

It definitely doesn't bloat `window` namespace and is more secure (window has more methods provided by browser).

Don't use eval - it's evil!

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` is unneeded here. To pass a callback, just pass the function name.  Functions are variables.

For example:

```
function test(a){
    alert(a);
}

function callback(b,a){
    b(a);
}

callback(test, 'dog'); //alerts 'dog'
```

So, in your code, `test(f1)` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to execute the function which is passed as a string. But its *deprecated* to use eval.

Example:

```
function test(someFunctionName) {
        eval(someFunctionName);
    }
```

Comment: @epascarello: I haven't used it ever in production code, so I don't know how evil it can be. But, if many wise people tried it and say it is, then I go with them :)

Comment: if people say jump off a bridge because it is the quickest way down would you do it? :) Eval is slow, eval can lead to security issues, and there are better solutions.

Comment: @epascarello: I won't. I certainly don't want to re-invent the wheel, I learn from other's experience as well, otherwise you will never move forward than where others have landed in the past. I take suggestions if they make sense to me :). Also I clearly stated in my answer that eval is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

write something like

```
function test(callback1) {
    eval(callback1 + "()");
}
```

then callback1 should be a string

Comment: I know. But the pragmatic developer may always prefer evil to another 3hrs of searching :)

Comment: Pragmatic programmer should also educate followers by doing research, which isn't so hard here. Eval is like SQL parametrized by concatenated strings. I wouldn't call one a programmer when using them.